# Dex: How to set dex.force.jumbo=true in Maven pom via android-maven-plugin?

Tags: android, maven, dex, android-maven-plugin

I have a situation where I want to set dex force jumbo mode to true in my Maven build.  How can I set the equivalent of this:

dex.force.jumbo=true

using the android-maven-plugin plugin?

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
  <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    ....
    <dex>
      <jvmArguments>
          <jvmArgument>-Xms1024m</jvmArgument>
          <jvmArgument>-Xmx2048m</jvmArgument>
      </jvmArguments>
    </dex>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: After looking at the source for DexMojo, I don't see any option for jumbo mode.  https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jayway/maven/plugins/android/phase08preparepackage/DexMojo.java

Answer (score 0):

Yes it ain't supported yet. But it's coming, maybe in 3.8.3 : https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/271